# Map only first level directory using tsconfig paths

Tags: angular, typescript

Having a folder hierarchy such as

```
app 
  entity
    entity.module.ts
    components
      entity
        entity.component.ts
  table
    table.module.ts
    components
      ...
```

I'd like to map to a path shortcut `@module` only

```
app/entity/entity.module.ts
app/table/table.module.ts
```

However, when using

```
"@module/*": ["app/entity/*", "app/table/*"]
```

all the sub-directories are accessible too.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you use one level wildcard `-*-`? I'm not sure

Comment: @Zooly not working unfortunately! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Haha had to try! 

Comment: @Zooly you did the right thing ;) What is strange is that I don't seem to find documentation which describes which kind of wildcards are supported

Comment: If you search in this page for : `supported glob wildcards`, there's a (small) list
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @Zooly but they don't seem to match in behavior. For example, for `*` thy write "*matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)*", while in reality all the subdirectories are matched too